# Angular 8 with asp.net mvc reposne return 404 not found on page refresh (no use of angular URL hashing)

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, web-config, response, page-refresh

I build an application using angular 8 project with production built in the content of a ASP.Net mvc 5 application
[project overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuWnJ.png)

When i refresh my page on a specific url not the default url, a request is sent to the server and return a 404 code response
so i added in my web.config this code below to redirect to a specific function on 404 error

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

The NotFound method is created as follow

```
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
       AppLog.Debug("", AppLog.ActionStatus.Requested);
       return View();
    }

   public ActionResult NotFound(string aspxerrorpath)
    {
       Response.StatusCode = 200;
       return View("Index");
    }
 }
```

when i refresh my page the code enters the NotFound Method and return the Index.cshtml page
that bootstraps my application

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    //var url = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.url.ToString()) ? "/" : ViewBag.url.ToString();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/img/Logos/Mini-logo.PNG">
    <meta name="author" content="codepixer">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>THE GATE DEVELOPMENT</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/Content/assets/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/Content/assets/Fonts/raleway-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/Content/assets/Fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/Content/assets/Fonts/raleway-medium-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/Content/assets/Fonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\" async></script>", "~/Script/Bundles")
</body>
</html>
```

and the browser navigates to this weird Url example:

```
http://localhost:9208/Home/NotFoundaspxerrorpath=/PropertiesByCountry/Cyprus
```

My initial url that i was intended to go to is:

```
http://localhost:9208/Home/PropertiesByCountry/Cyprus
```

Please help me fix this issue refreshing my angular 8 page without getting to use the 'useHash: true' in my router module

My goal is to configure the server to well redirect on page refresh

Comment: `http://localhost:9208/PropertiesByCountry/Cyprus` (Sorry my initial URL that i was intended to go to is without the home part)

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to have a 404 on the server and not on angular?

Comment: @user733421 When refreshing the page the browser will automatically make an HTTP call to the server ending with a 404 so the error will be thrown from the server

Comment: You newd to redirect all 404' to your index.html so angular can start again.